# AWS Cognito Update user login issue in iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on `AWS Cognito` login. It works fine in all cases such as SignUp, signIn, Forgot password etc. But it edit profile case, I am facing some technical problems. I edited my mobile number successfully.

In one of the case I provide wrong number and it throws an error like this,

> [AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: {"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"Invalid phone number format.”}

I am using this set of code to update my profile,

```
[[user updateAttributes:@[attributes]] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserUpdateAttributesResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
            //success
            return nil;
        }];
```

It provides only success responses. Failure responses are not coming inside this block. Can anyone help me how to get failure messages in this.  I tried so many ways but still troubling to get proper solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have done this by just calling continueWithBlock instead of continueWithSuccessBlock. Thats it..